# How do I fix "Add-Migration : Cannot add the link because the source file '' cannot be found"?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

When running `Add-Migration`, I get this error:

`Add-Migration : Cannot add the link because the source file '' cannot be found.`

I am using EF Core and Visual Studio 2017.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As often happens, I gave up after ages of head scratching, asked a SO question, and shortly afterwards found the problem!

In my case, the problem was not specifying the collection property in a `.WithMany()` clause when the collection property didn't match the table name. Replacing `.WithMany()` with `.WithMany(x => x.UpdateOperations)` fixed the problem.

Why that resulted in the given error message, I still have no idea, but I'll record this answer anyway in case someone else hits the same error for the same reason.

Answer (score 0):

Check if youre start up project is correct.
This must be the one with the connection string in the config.file